# New column added to Dataframe keeps dissapearing

Tags: python, pandas

I needed to clean my data, where I drop defective rows. For this I created a Day_number column to save the day numbers to use in the filtering.

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_loc)
cols = list(df.columns.values)
cols
df = df[[cols[-1]]+ [cols[9]]]
df.rename(columns={'mean-ghi': 'GHI'}, inplace = True)
df_filtered_nan = df.drop(df[df.GHI.isnull()].index)
df_filtered_nan['Day_number'] = df.Datetime.apply(lambda x: x.day)
df_filtered_nan.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)
```

This results in the following dataframe for df_filtered_nan:
[image: dataframe for df_filtered_nan]

However, when I carry out the filtering steps, for some reason the Day_number column disappears and I get an attribute error.

```
months_days_killed_count = {}
days_killed_count = 0
for day in df_filtered_nan.Day_number.unique():
    daywise = len(df_filtered_nan[df_filtered_nan.Day_number == day])
    print(daywise)
    if daywise != 1440:
        df_filtered_nan = df.drop(df_filtered_nan[df_filtered_nan.Day_number == day].index)
        days_killed_count += 1
    else:
        continue
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-117-c78d4b39ef13> in <module>
     24 days_killed_count = 0
     25 for day in df_filtered_nan.Day_number.unique():
---> 26     daywise = len(df_filtered_nan[df_filtered_nan.Day_number == day])
     27     print(daywise)
     28     if daywise != 1440:

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5137             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5138                 return self[name]
-> 5139             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5140 
   5141     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Day_number'
```

and now when I print the df_filtered_nan dataframe i get :
[image: df_filtered_nan dataframe printed after the filtering]

So, I can't for the life of me figure out what I have done wrong. Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```py
df_filtered_nan = df.drop(df_filtered_nan[df_filtered_nan.Day_number == day].index)
```

you are `drop`ping rows from `df` and **not** from `df_filtered_nan` and assigning it back to `df_filtered_nan`! Therefore whenever that `if` hits and this line is executed, `df_filtered_nan` becomes a cropped version of `df` which doesn't have the `Day_number` column; hence the error on the next turn of the `for` loop.

You probably need

```py
df_filtered_nan = df_filtered_nan.drop(df_filtered_nan[df_filtered_nan.Day_number == day].index)
```

i.e. drop from the `df_filtered_nan`. (also this would be more readable IMO if you do:

```py
row_indexes_to_drop = df_filtered_nan[df_filtered_nan.Day_number == day].index
df_filtered_nan = df_filtered_nan.drop(row_indexes_to_drop)
```

).